# Avoid rerendering child when passing object in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have a performance-optimized component like this one:

```js
const PerformanceComponent = ({style}) => {
     return <View style={style}>...</View>
}

export default React.memo(PerformanceComponent)
```

and I am using the component inside the parent like this:

```js
{someArray.map((style) => (
    <PerformanceComponent style={style} />
)}
```

I am passing different objects for `style`, it can look like this:

```js
const styles = {
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}
```

Now React.memo will not do the trick because I am passing an object and React will only compare the memoryaddress (I think its called **Shallow Compare**).

What are my options to **avoid unnecessary rerendering** (`PerformanceComponent`), even if the `styles`-object did not change?

Comment: you can use shouldComponentUpdate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers said, you need to pass a function as a second parameter to `React.memo` that will receive the previous prop and the current prop so you can decide if the component should be rerendered or not (just like `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle for class components).

Because comparing an entire object to see if anything changed can be a expensive operation (depending on the object) and because you can have multiple properties, one way to make sure it's efficient is to use lodash [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual).

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash'

const PerformanceComponent = ({style}) => {
     return <View style={style}>...</View>
}

export default React.memo(PerformanceComponent, isEqual)
```

This way you don't have to worry about implementing the `isEqual` and it also have a good performance.

Comment: Can you also answer the second question please

Comment: @mleister I can answer, but the problem is that I can't understand it. What do you mean by "wrap the style-object inside useMemo()" ?  What do you mean by wrap?

Comment: Like using `saveStyle = useMemo(() =>style);` inside the `.map()` function or anything similar (for referential equality). Or is this the completly wrong way?

Comment: @mleister you cant use `useMemo` inside `.map` but you could use `useMemo` with `someArray`, but that depends on where you get `someArray` from, so maybe add more code?

Comment: Okay question answered. The only way to go here is probably the `isEqual` function. Thank you!

Comment: @mleister glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

React.memo takes a second argument as comparison function. However, unlike shouldComponentUpdate it should return true to avoid re-rendering (although this is advised against as it can lead to bugs).

You can read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

In the comparison function you could either use lodash.isEqual if the object is large, or in your case something like this:

```
const isEqual = ({style: prevStyle}, {style: currStyle}) => {
  return prevStyle.width === currStyle.width && prevStyle.height == currStyle.height
}

export default React.Memo(PerformanceComponent, isEqual)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the memo call a second argument which is a function receiving prevProps and nextProps so you can write some logic to compare them and return true if you want to avoid unnecessary rerendering.

More info here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo