# Memoizing style object passed as props?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a (expensive to render) child component where a `customStyle` can be passed as a prop as such:

```
const Child = memo({ CustomStyle }){

  return(...)

})
```

But when the parent component passes `CustomStyle` the child component always re renders

```
function Parent(){
  return(
    <Child CustomStyle={{ color:"green" }} />
  )

}
```

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63505572/22302305) answer but I didn't want to add a dependency
So to avoid it I've tried `useMemo` on the prop itself as such:

```
const Child = memo({ CustomStyle }){
  CustomStyle = useMemo(() => CustomStyle, []) 

  return(...)

})
```

Will this cause any unexpected behaviour? Or is there a better way to pass objects without re rendering ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const Child = memo({ CustomStyle }){
>   CustomStyle = useMemo(() => CustomStyle, []) 
>
>   return(...)
>
> })
> ```

This code will not stop the component from rerendering, it will just cause that render to use the wrong data. If a new prop is passed in, `memo` will see that the prop changed and thus the component renders. Then when it's rendering, your use of `useMemo` will cause you to ignore the new value and use the old one. But the rendering still takes place, and so no performance is gained.

In order for `memo` to work, the prop that's passed in needs to not change. `useMemo` can help with this, but you need to do it *outside* of child. For example:

```
function Parent(){
  const style = useMemo(() => ({ color:"green" }), [])
  return(
    <Child CustomStyle={style} />
  )
}
```

If the style is completely static and doesn't depend on anything calculated during render, you could also move it outside of the component entirely, to a module-level constant:

```
const style = { color: "green" };
function Parent(){
  return(
    <Child CustomStyle={style} />
  )
}
```